# Гостям не видно главную страницу / Битрикс

Tags: битрикс, http-status-code-404, доступ

Если войти в панель администратора то главную страницу видно, если выйти из админки то пишет:

> Страница, которую вы ищете, не существует либо устарела.
>       Перейдите на Главную

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Права выставил, в чем может быть проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что у одного из инфоблоков был запрещен доступ для гостей.

> Путь: Контент > Инфоблоки > Типы инфоблоков > Название инфоблока

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]